# Add Scrollbar into Alert

Tags: javafx, scrollbar, alert

I have a situation at which i have to output a huge string in javafx `Alert`

```
 public static Optional<ButtonType> showAlertDialog(AlertType type, String title, String content) {
    TextArea textArea = new TextArea(content);
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setWrapText(true);
    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    gridPane.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    gridPane.add(textArea, 0, 0);

    Alert alert = new Alert(type);
    alert.setTitle(title);

    alert.setContentText(content);
    return alert.showAndWait();
}
```

when the string size exceeds the screen size, i can not read thehidden part of the string, how can i add `Scrollbar` to the `Alert`

Comment: Exeception Dialog: https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you're not adding the `TextArea` or `GridPane` to the `Alert`. You create them but then do nothing with them; instead, you're just setting the `contentText` of the `Alert`. You need to actually add the `TextArea`, which has built-in scrolling, to the `Alert`.

One way to do this is to set the `DialogPane.content` property rather than the `contentText` property.

```
private Optional<ButtonType> showAlert(AlertType type, String title, String content) {
  Alert alert = new Alert(type);
  alert.setTitle(title);

  TextArea area = new TextArea(content);
  area.setWrapText(true);
  area.setEditable(false);

  alert.getDialogPane().setContent(area);
  alert.setResizable(true);

  return alert.showAndWait();
}
```

Another way is to add the `TextArea` as the `expandableContent` and have the `contentText` be a shorter message.

```
private Optional<ButtonType> showAlert(AlertType type, String title, String shortMessage, String fullMessage) {
  Alert alert = new Alert(type);
  alert.setTitle(title);
  alert.setContentText(shortMessage);

  TextArea area = new TextArea(fullMessage);
  area.setWrapText(true);
  area.setEditable(false);

  alert.getDialogPane().setExpandableContent(area);

  return alert.showAndWait();
}
```